# Assign Parent Document Button Click Event from Child Document Controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

I am new to angular.

I have **Document A** which has **Save** Button and an `IFrame`.

The Iframe has **Document B** with angular Controller where `saveClick()` is defined.

Upon Document B Load I want to assign `saveClick()` function to the parent document button so that when user clicks on Save button `saveClick()` of the child controller should be executed.

I used to do this in **JavaScript** as

```
parent.parent.saveClick = function () { ... }
```

with button defined as

```
<button id='nobtnAdd' disabled onclick='return saveClick();' 
        title="New Record (Alt+A)">Save
</button>
```

Document A does not use angular JS now , but i can use it if required.

Iframe will load a variety of documents with angular JS where the controller will assign the save routine.

How do i achieve this using angular ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using `postMessage` API to communicate between windows. Or set up parent function in angular `run()` block. In both cases can use angular events to communicate with the rest of the app

Comment: @charlietfl any ideas how to do it using run() ? thanks

Comment: `$window.saveClick = function(){ /* angular event broadcast here */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use `run()` block of angular app to wrap an event broadcast into a global scope function. Then your iframe parent code would be the same

```
angular
   .module('myApp',[....])
   .run(function($window, $rootScope){
      $window.saveClick = function(){ 
         $rootScope.$broadcast('saveClick');
      };

   }).controller('someCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.$on('saveClick', function(){
        alert('Iframe clicked')
      });
   });
```

Personally I would use postMessage API so you can avoid using global scope.

Comment: No..code in answer is all in the parent angular app. You mentioned you weren't using angular in child. Hmmm ..maybe I got this backwards as to which is which

Comment: will it execute saveClick of child controller? because that is where the save routine is defined.

Comment: After re-reading question again it is confusing what exactly you are needing to do. Are you trying to communicate between both windows?

Comment: main document has toolbar with save button. The child document defines actual save routine implementation.

Comment: So click on main doc needs to be passed to iframe and into angular app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109323/discussion-between-deb-and-charlietfl).